# Spreadsheet, result of multiple connected formulas depending on value from list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A little bit frustrating as I knew how to do it years ago and right now I can't event ask Google accurate question to find the answer so I'm comming here :)

The sample spreadsheet will be almost self explanatory:
https://ethercalc.net/onpoo16pjeld

Extremely simplified version would be:

```
    A        | B
1 | input:   |100 
2 | formula1 |=B1 * 1.5
3 | formula2 |=B2 + 20
4 | 90       |=result of B3 when B1 = A4 
5 | 150      |=result of B3 when B1 = A5 
6 | 200      |=result of B3 when B1 = A6
```

I need result of last formula in the chain basing on different initial values.

I'll appreciate Google Sheet formulas, thank you.

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this,please describe the spreadsheet structure and add the a sample data directly into the question body. Also question should be specific, so choose one spreadsheet app. Only include both in you need to assure compatibility and in such case you should specify that.

Comment: On B4, what result should be shown  when B1 = A4 is false? (the same for B5, and B6)

Comment: That's not strictly the false/true condition, I mean here that B1 is like variable that takes the value from A4:A6 (depending on row)

Comment: Does this help [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)?

Comment: Honestly I don't know how I could apply it to solve my case

Comment: Please provide some sample cases (input data and the corresponding expected results)

Comment: I can't edit my question after your edits of my table sample "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."
But everything is already there, B4 result should be 155 (becase firstly: 90 * 1.5 (B2 formula), then 135 + 20 (B3 formula)

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75197528/revisions then go to the last revision done by you, click rollback. Then go back to the question and add the changes that you need. This is just a suggestion. If you think that your question is clear enough, you can keep your question as it is.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the question is that you are asking for something like Excel's 'Data Tables' function, where (given some sort of mathematical model where the logic is chained over multiple cells from 1 or 2 input cell(s) each containing a single value into one output cell) the user can define the input and output cells and then create a table where Excel feeds multiple values into the input cell(s) and records the output value for each one according to the model. Google Sheets doesn't natively support this; the add-on below claims to replicate the Data Table functionality (https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/whatif/430660745752) but I have no experience with it. The 'best' option is still probably to condense all the logic into one arrayformula as per Tedinoz's answer - if there's a concern that this will make the model more difficult to understand because the individual steps are no longer spread out over multiple cells then it should be possible to use LAMBDAs to label all the steps to make the arrayformula easier to follow.

Answer (score -1):

This formula assumes that the value in Cell B2 = Cell B1 x 120%

Enter this formula in cell F2:
`=arrayformula(((E2:E7+(E2:E7*2/5))*1.15)+ (IF((E2:E7*2/5)>150, 50, 80)))`

---

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: But this was just simplified example, your answer is just copying all the formulas into single one... that is definitely not the solution I'm looking for

Comment: I've misunderstood your question. I do understand what you mean by "right now I can't event ask Google accurate question to find the answer", but if you can't find a good way to express what you want, then it does make it somewhat more difficult for us to find the solution ;) I'll leave this answer so that others don't make the same mistake. BTW, I don't suppose you're looking for some kind of "Goal Seek"?